# How to print a float value of 6 digit precision in C++?

Tags: c++, decimal, precision, digit

By default I'm getting 4 digit precision and when I use `setprecision(6)` the last digits of the variable come in random like `1/3=0.333369`.

Comment: It looks like you are limited by the `float` type itself, why not use `double`? But even this type has limitations.

Comment: @Potatoswatter IEEE 754 floats don't work like that ;)

Comment: @fge (comment deleted because the content was moved to the answer) yes, they do, `1/3.f` will produce the closest `float` to 1/3 and the error will be less than one part in ten million.

Comment: `1/3` is an integer division with result `0`. To get a `float` with the correct value, at least one operand must be `float`, for example `float x=1.f/3.f;`. This followed by `std::cout<<x;` will typically print out `0.333333` (provided `std::cout` is its original state: 6 digits are the default).

Answer (score 4):

`float` has about 7 decimal digits of precision, due to its use of 24 binary digits to store the digits of the number. As far as output is concerned, `setprecision(6)` does everything you could ask for.

It's likely you are losing precision, for example by subtracting two numbers with similar values and printing the result. The quick solution is to change the computations to use `double` or `long double`. But to make any guarantees about the precision of a floating-point result, you need to understand how FP works and analyze how your formula is getting computed.

See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).